# Set Jupyter Lab working directory to the directory where Jupyter was started, not the parent directory of the notebook?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter, ipython, jupyter-lab

Normally, the working directory of a notebook is its parent directory. So if I create a notebook `~/projects/abcd/eda/nb1.ipynb`, then the working directory for `nb1.ipynb` will be `~/projects/abcd/eda`.

I started Jupyter Lab in `~/projects/abcd`. I want the default working directory of all notebooks to be `~/projects/abcd`. Is it possible to achieve this? Ideally it should be something I can either attach to each notebook itself, or something I can set on Jupyter Lab upon startup, so that if someone else needs to use my project, they will be able to benefit from the same behavior.

I am OK with solutions that focus specifically on IPykernel, but a solution that works for all kernels (IRKernel, IJulia, Xeus, etc) would be best.

Comment: @krassowski I don't like that prompt for the duplicate question. The answer there is really unsatisfying, even though this is definitely a duplicate question. It might come across as patronizing to a newbie.